# AWS EC2 - FTP return error 451 when trying to upload new file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp, centos

I am running two t2.medium  EC2 servers on AWS. They are both launched from the same AMI and with similar settings, FTP (except passwords ofc) and locations. The only difference in the two servers is the content in the /var/www/html folder.

So far they have been working as expected but yesterday something weird started happening. Whenever I try to upload a new version of a (php) file on one of the servers, it fails and returns the error "server did not report OK, got 451". I've tried different FTP-users, different IDEs and rebooting my EC2-server without any luck. This only happens on one of the servers and it started happening "out of the blue"

Any suggestions how to fix this or at least in what direction I should continue my debugging?

Comment: the 451 response is coming from your FTP server (it translates to: "Requested action aborted. Local error in processing"). This indicates that there is no issue with the underlying AWS resources (VPC, network connection, EC2), but that the problem is in the operating system/software running on the ec2 instance.
I would check the log files of your ftp server for potential errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by @korgen lead me to the error log of the server. When I ran `sudo less /var/log/secure` I quickly saw the error message: error:

> *Failed to write to /var/log/btmp: No space left on device*

I checked the storage volume by running the command `df -h` and I saw that 20.0 / 20.0 GB was in use. I increased the server volume size in AWS and after a quick reboot it all now works again.

I hope this helps a future lost soul :-)